# spinner with a rectangular border

Tags: android, border, android-spinner

I am developing an android app inn which I want to use a Spinner with a white border as shown in the image.

[image: Spinner Demo]

Please help me how can I achieve the same.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The background isn't even white.

Comment: Sorry i meant white border..i have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best Solution for such things is to Create **9 patch image**.

You need to create 9 patch image(Rectangle Box) which helps you to set the spinner with different resolution.

After creating **9 patch image use it as a background of the Spinner.**