# How to remove white stripe when applying a custom item to dropdown view for a Spinner?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using a custom layout for a `Spinner DropDownview`, it has a brown background with white letters. There are some white stripes appearing at the bottom of the view[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbYqG.png), that I want to remove but I don't know how neither why they are appearing;

[image: spinner with more items]
[image: spinner with one item]

here are the code that I'm using for the `spinner_dropdown_item`:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="@color/marrom"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/txt_min_height"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/md_keylines"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_subtitle"
    tools:text="spinner dropdown item" />
```

and the `getDropdownView` inside the spinner adapter:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    T element = elements.get(position);
    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(getDropdownLayout(), parent, false);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
    textView.setText(getDisplayName(element));
    return textView;
}
```

where the function `getDropdownLayout` returns the layout above

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I stumbled upon a suggestion:[spinner with a rectangular border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758446/spinner-with-a-rectangular-border).

Create 9 patch image(Rectangle Box) which helps you to set the spinner with different resolution.

After creating 9 patch image use it as a background of the Spinner.

Here is a link that makes creating that 9pacth image simple:http://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Here is my example:

[image]

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. the white stripe is still showing.